# How to get a canonical link from HTML head using Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to get the defined canonical link from a webpage using Nokogiri:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://test.com/somepage">
```

It's the `href` I'm after.

Whatever I try it doesn't seem to work. This is what I have:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)

canon = page.xpath('//canonical/@href')
puts canon
```

This doesn't return anything, not even an error.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to get the attribute but that is not how you do it.

You can use this:

```
page.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href')
```

What it says is: get me a link element anywhere in the document that has a  `rel` attribute that equals `"canonical"` and when you find that node, get me its `href`  attribute.

The full answers is:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)

canon = page.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href')
puts canon
```

What you tried to do is get a node that is called "canonical", not the attribute.

Comment: `canon` won't be a String, it'll be an Attr object, which won't act like a String. It'll be stringified when you use `puts` but that's obscuring the real object which will cause problems down the line if you try to treat it as anything but what it is.

Comment: The main point is that it will grep what it has to. `puts canon` is just to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of using CSS selectors over XPath as they're more readable:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<link rel="canonical" href="https://test.com/somepage">')
doc.at('link[rel="canonical"]')['href'] # => "https://test.com/somepage"
```

---

There's come confusion about what Nokogiri, and XPath, are returning when accessing a node parameter. Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<link rel="canonical" href="https://test.com/somepage">')
```

Here's how I'd do it using CSS:

```
doc.at('link[rel="canonical"]').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
doc.at('link[rel="canonical"]')['href'].class # => String

doc.at('link[rel="canonical"]')['href'] # => "https://test.com/somepage"
```

XPath, while more powerful, is also capable of making you, or Nokogiri, Ruby or the CPU, do more work.

First, [`xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#xpath-instance_method), which is the XPath-specific version of [`search`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#search-instance_method) returns a NodeSet, not a node or an element. A NodeSet is akin to an array of nodes, which can bite you if you're not aware of what you've got. From the [NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) documentation:

> A NodeSet contains a list of Nokogiri::XML::Node objects. Typically a NodeSet is return as a result of searching a Document via Nokogiri::XML::Searchable#css or Nokogiri::XML::Searchable#xpath

If you are looking for a specific node, or only a single instance of a particular type of node, then use [`at`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#at-instance_method), or if you want to be picky, use [`at_css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#at_css-instance_method) or [`at_xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#at_xpath-instance_method). (Nokogiri can usually figure out what you mean when using `at` or `search` but sometimes you have to use the specific method to give Nokogiri a nudge in the right direction.) Using `at` in the above example shows it returns the node itself, and once you've got the node it's trivial to get the value of any parameter by treating it as a hash.

`xpath`, `search` and `css` all return NodeSets, so, like an array, you need to point to the actual element you want then access the parameter:

```
doc.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').first.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Attr

doc.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').text # => "https://test.com/somepage"
```

Notice that `'//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href'` results in Nokogiri returning an Attr object, not text. You can print that object, and Ruby will stringify it, but it won't behave like a String resulting in errors if you try to treat it like one. For instance:

```
doc.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').first.downcase # => NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x007faace115d20>
```

Instead, use [`text`](http://text) or `content` to get the text value:

```
doc.at('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Attr

doc.at('//link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').text # => "https://test.com/somepage"
```

or get the element itself and then access the parameter like you would a hash:

```
doc.at('//link[@rel="canonical"]').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element

doc.at('//link[@rel="canonical"]')['href'] # => "https://test.com/somepage"
```

either of which will return a String.

Also notice I'm not using `@href` to return the Attr in this example, I'm only getting the Node itself then using `['href']` to return the text of the parameter. It's a shorter selector and makes more sense, at least to me, since Nokogiri isn't having to return the Attr object which you then have to convert using `text` or possibly run into problems when you accidentally treat it as a String.

Comment: CSS selectors are nice but are a bit slower and can be a lot harder to migrate to other languages or for someone new to start learning.

Comment: Most web developers understand CSS, either from using jQuery or style-sheets so it's very easy for them to jump in that way. Migrating to other languages isn't necessarily hard; I've used other parsers that understood CSS.